# Adding the : colon in the URL

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I am a newbie in shell scripting, I have a text file like this:

```
`http://example.com    http//example.net http//www.flugov/individualfamily/prevention/index.html`
```

I wanted to replace the http which does not have the colon by http: I tried this way:

```
sed 's/http/http:/g' file
```

What I get is the extra colon in URL

```
http:://example.com http://example.net http://www.flugov/individualfamily/prevention/index.html
```

Any suggestions to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure there is no `:` after `http` and print that character back:

```
$ sed -r 's/http([^:])/http:\1/g' file
http://example.com    http://example.net http://www.flugov/individualfamily/prevention/index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Through perl,

```
perl -pe 's~http(?!:)~http:~g' file
```

**Example:**

```
$ echo 'http://example.com    http//example.net http//www.flugov/individualfamily/prevention/index.html' | perl -pe 's~http(?!:)~http:~g'
http://example.com    http://example.net http://www.flugov/individualfamily/prevention/index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, consume any and all colons:  `s/http:*/http:/g`